# Opencart: call method from another controller

Tags: php, templates, opencart

I need to call in **checkout/confirm.tpl** file a custom function that i've made in **controller/product.php**

what's the best way to make this?

i've tried this, but doesn't work:

```
$productController = $this->load->model('product/product');
$productController->customFunction();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **MVC**

   - in an MVC architecture, a template serves **solely** for rendering/displaying data; it shouldn't (*) call controller/model functions **nor it shouldn't execute SQL queries** as I have seen in many *third-party* modules (and even in **answers** here at SO).
2. **`$productController = $this->load->model('product/product');`**

   - nifty eye has to discover that you are trying to load a **model** into a variable named by *controller* and you are also trying to use it in such way. Well, for your purpose there would have to be a method `controller()` in class `Loader` - which is not (luckily)
3. **How it should be done?**

   - sure there is a way how to *access* or *call* controller functions from within templates. In MVC a callable function that is invoked by routing is called **action**. Using this sentence I can now say that **you can invoke an action** (controller function) **by accessing certain URL**.

So let's say your controller is `CatalogProductController` and the method you want to invoke is `custom()` - in this case accessing this URL

```
http://yourstore.com/index.php?route=catalog/product/custom
```

you will make sure that the `custom()` method of `CatalogProductController` is invoked/accessed.

You can access such URL in many ways - as a cURL request, as a link's *href* or via AJAX request, to name some. In a PHP scope even `file_get_contents()` or similar approach will work.

(*) By *shouldn't* I mean that it is (**unfortunately**) possible in OpenCart but such abuse is against MVC architecture.

Answer (score 7):

yes i find the right answer finally!!! sorry for last bad answer

```
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        return $this->load->controller('product/ready');
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick note: you can also pass arguments as `$this->load->controller('product/ready', array('foo'=>'bar'))` and access them as `public function index($args)` in your controller.

Comment: aexl, could I do this!! it will be so useful, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

`$this->load->controller('sale/box',$yourData);`

To call `ShipmentDate()` function of box Controller

`$this->load->controller('sale/box/ShipmentDate',$yourData);`

Answer (score 2):

May be something like this could help you (or anyone who's interested)

```
// Load seo pro
require_once(DIR_CATALOG."/controller/common/seo_pro.php"); // load file
$seoPro = new ControllerCommonSeoPro($this->registry); // pass registry to constructor

$url = HTTP_CATALOG . $seoPro->rewrite(
 $this->url('information/information&information_id=' . $result['information_id'])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return $this->load->controller('error/not_found');
```

Comment: An explanation of how this code fixes the problem would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

in laravel its so simple just write Controller::call('ApplesController@getSomething');

but there i cant made better than this

```
$config = new Config();
// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$this->registry->set('response', $response);


$action = new Action('product/ready');
$controller = new Front($this->registry);
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));
$response->output();
```

in this case its well call product/ready